# Call web services from IIS it works slowly

Tags: web-services, iis-7.5

I'm developing asp.net mvc web application that calls third party web services.

I'm not sure about web services but looks like that they are java web services. They work perfect when I call them from windows console application or run my site under asp.net development server. But when I host my site under IIS 7.5 (I check it under Windows 7 32x and Windows Web Server 64x) performance is degraded in 10 time.

Could anybody suggest me with settings which I should check or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea that I have, it is using Reversed Proxy for matching data that pass.

I've tired to use Fiddler 2 in [this way](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/01/10/HTTP_Debugging_Using_Reverse_Proxies_And_Port_Forwarders.aspx). But what a pity I have trouble because web services are hosted via https.

Somebody has idea how to solve this?

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Help/ReverseProxy.asp
how to configure fiddler.. but https is still under question